# Using Data Validation and limiting cell characters to 10, but copy and pasting will override the Data Validation and the Error Box won't appear

Tags: excel, vba

I have code below, but it won't override and create an error message when copy and pasting onto a Data Validation cell

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Test(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Does the validation range still have validation?
    If HasValidation(Range("A2:A3")) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Application.Undo
        MsgBox "Error: You cannot paste data into these cells." & _
        "Please use the drop-down to enter data instead.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub

Private Function HasValidation(r) As Boolean
    'Returns True if every cell in Range r uses Data Validation
    On Error Resume Next
    x = r.Validation.Type
    If Err.Number = 0 Then HasValidation = True Else HasValidation = False
End Function
```

Comment: Did you change the `Worksheet_Change` handler to `Worksheet_Test`?

Comment: yes i did, but I've tried Worksheet_Change and Worksheet_Test. The name of my sheet is Test though shouldn't I use Test because it is just a name.

Comment: No... it has to be `Worksheet_Change`, you can't change that.

Comment: It's not just a name - it needs to be Worksheet_Change and it needs to be in the worksheet code module

Comment: I see, so I did change it back to Worksheet_Change and it is in a module, but does not work.

Comment: So should I be adding something like "& (Len) > 10 " after If HasValidation(Range("A2:A3"))

Comment: It needs to be in the *worksheet* code module, not a regular module.